# When are path algebras of quivers hereditary.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, quiver

Suppose we have a finite quiver with relations, possibly with oriented cycles. Is it known when the path algebra of this quiver (with relations) is hereditary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $A = kQ/I$ where $Q$ is a quiver and $I$ are the relations.  Then $A$ is hereditary if and only if $Q$ is finite, connected, and acyclic, and $I = (0)$.  This is essentially Theorem 1.7 in Chapter VII of Assem, Simson, Skowronski - Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras.

Comment: That's under the assumption that $A$ is finite dimensional. For the infinite-dimensional case a counterexample is the first Weyl algebra $A=\mathbb{C}\langle x,y\rangle/(xy-yx-1)$, which is hereditary, see e.g. [Lam: Lectures on Modules and Rings (2.32 (h))].

Comment: Ok thanks. Are there any general results for infinite dimensional path algebras? (Sorry, i do not have acces to a math libary at the moment)

Comment: Sadly I know nothing about the infinite dimensional case.